# Export Table of Contents from Jupyter Lab to a Cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, jupyter-lab, tableofcontents

I work on a Jupyter Lab Notebook with the TOC (Table of Contents) extension installed (https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-toc), which works great!

However I want to export this notebook on various formats (html, pdf...) so I need the TOC to be generated or inserted in a cell. But unfortunately I can't find how to do this.

Is there a command line or a trick to do so?

---

EDIT: This feature is not implemented yet, however if you use the extensions for jupyter notebook, it works! Having to switch from a jupyter to another is a bit annoying, but at least the job is done!

Comment: I don't believe it's possible in jupyterlab-toc, at the moment. There are a few open issues requesting this, such as: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-toc/issues/84 and https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-toc/issues/97

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought... :-/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the option 'Export Notebook to Html\_toc' on the 'Export Notebook as...' menu in Jupyter Lab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63123830/how-can-i-get-the-option-export-notebook-to-html-toc-on-the-export-notebook-a)