# How can I get the option 'Export Notebook to Html_toc' on the 'Export Notebook as...' menu in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

- How can all of the `jupyter nbconvert` export options be enabled from the `Export Notebook As...` menu in Jupyter lab?

  - Specifically, **how can I get the option to `Export Notebook to Html_toc` on the menu?**
- Following a clean installation of Anaconda, the default export menu is:

  - [image]
- However, as shown in this issue [Add nbconvert export options to `File --> Export notebook as` #7612](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/7612), there are additional options, which can be run from the console, but do not display in the menu.
- The full menu would look like:

  - [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- This answer is a roundabout hack for enabling the full menu in Jupyter Lab
- In this situation, I have a clean installation of Anaconda, which includes Jupyter Lab and Jupyter Notebook.
- Upon entering Jupyter Lab, only the minimal Export options are available.

### To enable the Html_toc Export option, do the following

1. Go to the Extension Manager in Jupyter Lab and install `@jupyterlab/toc`

   - [image]
   - Current versions of Jupyter Lab already have the TOC, so this step may not be necessary.
2. Shut down Jupyter lab and go to the Anaconda Prompt
3. If your version of `nbconvert` is greater than 5.6.1, then do `conda install -c conda-forge "nbconvert=5.6.1"`
4. Run `conda install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` or `conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` per [Installing jupyter_contrib_nbextensions Guide](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#conda).

   - This will install a number of extensions to `\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\jupyter_contrib_nbextensions\\nbextensions\\`
   - There are `pip` install options in the guide, but I haven't tried this for a manual installation of Jupyter Lab and Jupyter Notebook
5. Run `jupyter contrib nbextension install --user`
6. From the Anaconda Prompt, run `jupyter notebook`

   - During loading of the Jupyter Notebook environment, there where warnings as follows `[jupyter_nbextensions_configurator] nbextension '...' has duplicate listings`.
   - One location was `\\Anaconda3\\...`, as mentioned above, and the other was `\\Users\\...\\AppData\\\Roaming\\jupyter\\nbextensions\\...`
   - This could be because I had a previous installation of Anaconda, but I resolved this issue by renaming `\\Users\\...\\AppData\\\Roaming\\jupyter\\nbextensions\\...` to `\\Users\\...\\AppData\\\Roaming\\jupyter\\nbextensions_old\\...`
7. Go to the `Nvextensions` tab, select the option for `Table of Contents (2)`, and `Enable` it.

   - [image]
8. Quit / Logout of Jupyter Notebook
9. From the Anaconda prompt, go the `jupyter lab`
10. Now all of the `Export Notebook As...` options will be enabled in the file menu.

    - Including, and specifically `Export Notebook to Html_toc`

### Examples

- [Here are examples](https://trenton3983.github.io/#notebooks) of HTML notebooks with a Table of Contents output from Jupyter Lab. See the DataCamp notebooks.

Comment: alas "nbconvert=5.6.1" does not work with latest jupyter (lab)

Comment: @cs0815 I was wondering when it would break. I haven’t seen an alternative. It’s annoying that HTML TOC isn’t a native option.

Comment: @cs0815 let me know the last version of JL this works with, if you know it. I’ll add it to the answer.

Comment: don't know sorry )-: